# iText and DocuSign - PDF Validation Error

Tags: docusignapi, itext7

My company has one program that creates a pdf from a template pdf and another that sends that pdf through DocuSign.  It has worked all along for I don't know how long (it predates me working here).  But lately when I try to send the pdf through DocuSign, I get a PDF Validation Error.  This just started happening in the last week or two.  I can open the file in Adobe Acrobat Reader and print it with CutePDF Writer and then it works fine.  Just don't know why DocuSign all of a sudden doesn't like the pdf's.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the exact error and also the code that uploads the PDF to DocuSign?

Comment: You have tagged your question [tag:itext7] but don't mention it in your question body. How does it relate?

Comment: If you happen to create the PDFs in question using iText 7, please make sure you use an up-to-date version of the library: The very early iText 7.0.x versions sometimes create PDFs with an error that in practice causes issues only in signing contexts.

Answer (score 0):

### You have a potential regression bug.

#### Confirming a regression bug

1. Isolate: does the PDF work via the DocuSign web app? If it does then the problem is with your API integration and you'll need to determine the problem there.
2. If you have an older pdf that was used to successfully create an envelope, test it to see if it still works (via the DocuSign web app). If it does then your PDF software changed. Not a regression bug.
3. The best test is that a PDF that previously worked no longer does.

#### If you've confirmed a regression bug

Please contact [DocuSign developer support](https://support.docusign.com/en/caseOverview?dfl=1)

You'll either give them the PDF to analyze or, if it contains private data, you should create a test pdf that also doesn't work via the DocuSign we app.

### Catching regression issues sooner

DocuSign strongly recommends that all software developers build automated tests for their software to exercise the DocuSign integration/APIs.

Then set up the tests to automatically run daily against the test platform (demo.docusign.net). Accounts on that system are no charge.

If your automated test detects a regression problem then you should immediately contact DocuSign Developer Support.

#### Regression bugs are rare

DocuSign uses thousands of automated regression tests to ensure that new releases don't cause regression problems. But issues do slip through.

By testing against the test platform, you have the opportunity to discover an issue (and alert DocuSign) a week or more before the scheduled production release.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions.  They were very good suggestions.  However, it turned out that it was my pdf template that was being used to create the pdf.  It had Adobe signature fields in it and it appears that Docusign has decided they don't like Adobe signature fields.  I removed those fields from the pdf form and it worked fine.